# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to import a video ID using AWS Amplify's DataStore and the useRoute() hook from @react-navigation/native library.

So far everything is working, but I keep getting this error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

I tried searching on google and I kind of found some similar stuff, but none of the solutions would work for my app.

My code:

```
    const [video, setVideo] = useState<Video | null >(null)
    const [comments, setComments] = useState<Comment[]>([])
    const route = useRoute()
    const videoId = route.params?.id

    useEffect(() => {
        DataStore.query(Video, videoId).then(setVideo)
    }, [videoId])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-navigation`'s [`useRoute`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/cd75d2e257f6e0aca33169ba3fd5a4d8f6d04a2e/packages/core/src/useRoute.tsx#L12) needs to be provided with explicit type parameter to be able to type the returned result.

First, you need to defined somewhere full list of routes of your application and corresponding route properties:

```ts
type AppRouteParamList = {
    Home: undefined // undefined means Home route doesn't have route parameters
    Video: { id: string } | undefined
}
```

Then inside your component you have to annotate `useRoute` with correct type parameter:

```ts
import { AppRouteParamList } from './routes.ts'
import { useRoute, RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native'

const route = useRoute<RouteProp<AppRouteParamList, 'Video'>>()
const videoId = route.params?.id
```